# Pegando valor do array mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou passando um array angular por JSON desta forma:

```
 $scope.gravaItem = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/TaxaPreco/SalvarItens',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { DeJson: JSON.stringify($scope.items) },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log('Data received: ');
                console.log(result);
            }

        })
    };
```

E no `controller` desta forma:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> SalvarItens(string DeJson)
    {
        var arr = DeJson.Split(',');
        var item = new TarifasPrecosItens()
        {
            De = arr[0],
            Ate = "01:01",
            Fracao = 0,
            RepeteACada = 0,
            TipoValor = 1,
            Valor =5,
            TararifaPrecosId = 25,
        };

        _context.TarifasPrecosItens.Add(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();


        return new JsonResult(DeJson);
    }
```

no De ele recebe o seguinte valor:

> [{"de":"00:01"

Como posso resolver o valor corretamente? Eu preciso pegar todos os valores, neste caso, eu deveria pegar apenas:

> 00:01

Answer (score 0):

Eu não usaria o stringify para passar a lista para o controller. Se itens é um array de strings faça simplesmente:

```
$scope.gravaItem = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/TaxaPreco/SalvarItens',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { DeJson: $scope.items },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('Data received: ');
            console.log(result);
        }

    })
};
```

e no controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SalvarItens(List<string> DeJson)
{
    var item = new TarifasPrecosItens()
    {
        De = DeJson.First(),
        Ate = "01:01",
        Fracao = 0,
        RepeteACada = 0,
        TipoValor = 1,
        Valor =5,
        TararifaPrecosId = 25,
    };

    _context.TarifasPrecosItens.Add(item);
    _context.SaveChanges();


    return new JsonResult(DeJson);
}
```

Existe um excelente artigo que mostra como usar o $scope com Asp.NET MVC:
[Call MVC Controller from AngularJS using AJAX and JSON in ASP.Net MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-MVC-Controller-from-AngularJS-using-AJAX-and-JSON-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

Att